# SQL Delete * causing performance issues

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a PL/SQL file that at one point needs to delete an entire table. The challenge is:

1. ***truncate table*** cannot be used since the DB user in question cannot be provided rights to execute DDL commands (owing to SOX compliance)
2. ***delete ****  works well in case the table has lesser number of records. However, the table might have millions of records in which case the redo log file size increases drastically causing performance issues

Following solutions work:

1. Increasing the redo log file size
2. Deleting records in batch mode (within nested transactions)

Is there any better and more efficient way to address this issue?

Comment: Why not drop the table and re-create it?  Or rename the table (into a stashed name) and recreate it?

Comment: " the DB user in question cannot be provided rights to execute DDL" - then run that procedure with a user that does, documenting it as necessary for compliance. Truncate is the right thing here.

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` as this is obviously only about Oracle.

Comment: why dont you use DROP command!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the redo log file size is the problem, you can delete in portions with COMMIT after each delete. For example:

```
LOOP 
  --delete 1000000 records in each iteration
  DELETE FROM tmp_test_table 
  WHERE 1=1--:WHERE_CONDITION
  AND   rownum <= 1000000;
  -- exit when there is no more to delete
  EXIT WHEN SQL%rowcount = 0;
  COMMIT; 
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways that you can use :
Use partitioning:  The fastest way to do a mass delete is to drop an Oracle partition.
Tune the delete subquery:  Many Oracle deletes use a where clause subquery and optimizing the subquery will improve the SQL delete speed.
Use bulk deletes:  Oracle PL/SQL has a bulk delete operator that often is faster than a standard SQL delete.
Drop indexes & constraints:  If you are tuning a delete in a nighttime batch job, consider dropping the indexes and rebuilding them after the delete job as completed.
Small pctused:  For tuning mass deletes you can reduce freelist overhead by setting Oracle to only re-add a block to the freelists when the block is dead empty by setting a low value for pctused.
Parallelize the delete job:  You can run massive delete in parallel with the parallel hint.  If you have 36 processors, the full-scan can run 35 times faster (cpu_count-1)
Consider NOARCHIVELOG:  Take a full backup first and bounce the database into NOLOGGING mode for the delete and bounce it again after, into ARCHIVELOG mode.
Use CTAS:  Another option you can try would be to create a new table using CTAS where the select statement filters out the rows that you want to delete. Then do a rename of the original followed by a rename of the new table and transfer constraints and indexes.
Lastly, resist the temptation to do "soft" deletes, a brain-dead approach that can be fatal.

Comment: This is plagiarism: original at http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_delete_tuning.htm ; cite your sources.

Answer (score 0):

This method has advantages.
You can create a table in the required tablespace without fragmentation on the required partition of the disk.
The physical re-creation of the table will remove the fragmentation of the tables and remove the chained rows.

If you need to remove 60-99% of the rows from the table. `emp`
Then you need to make a new table `emp_new`.

```
create table emp_new ;
```

Copy the required rows to a new table

```
insert into emp_new select * from emp where date_insert> sysdate-30
```

Create indexes on a new table

```
create index PK_EMP on emp_new.
```

drop the old emp table

```
drop table emp.
```

Rename the new table to the old name.

`rename table emp_new to emp`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as mentioned in my question I have a constraint that the DDL statements cannot be used

Answer (score -2):

In Oracle PL/SQL DDL statements should use Execute Immediate before the statement. Hence you should use:

```
execute immediate 'truncate table schema.tablename';
```

As well as you can also use

```
DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('TRUNCATE TABLE tablename;');
```

Try anyone it may work in your case

Comment: The question explicitly states that they have no privilege to use truncate. The syntax is irrelevant.